# Make a move_uploaded_file after imagecopyresampled in PHP

Tags: php, image

I'm trying to resize image in PHP.

But after all this work how can I use the `move_uploaded_file` function to move the `tmp_file` file to it final directory ?

Here's my code:

```
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($_FILES['REG_Image']['tmp_name']);

// Target dimensions
$max_width = 1014;
$max_height = 768;

// Get current dimensions
$old_width  = imagesx($image);
$old_height = imagesy($image);

if($old_width > $max_height) {

    // Calculate the scaling we need to do to fit the image inside our frame
    $scale = min($max_width/$old_width, $max_height/$old_height);

    // Get the new dimensions
    $new_width  = ceil($scale*$old_width);
    $new_height = ceil($scale*$old_height);

    // Create new empty image
    $new = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);

    // Resize old image into new
    imagecopyresampled($new, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $old_width, $old_height);

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`imagejpeg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php) instead after

```
imagecopyresampled($new, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width,$new_height, $old_width, $old_height);
imagejpeg($new, "/path/to/image.jpeg");
```

this will save the image to the new path that you have specified as `image.jpeg`. You can use [`imagepng`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php) as well if you want a PNG image as output.